# Usage of variable in {..}

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Can someone explain why the following code

```
for i in {1..5};do
echo "hello"
done
```

prints

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

but the following

```
num=5

for i in {1..$num};do
echo "hello"
done
```

prints

```
hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because brace expansion happens before variable expansion.

You can use `seq` instead:

```
num=5
for i in $(seq 1 $num) ; do
    echo hello
done
```